# I am having hard time writing Jest test for timer

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to write jest test for react-countdown-now timer. It should be pretty simple, but i am new to jest and i am having hard time writing it.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Countdown, { zeroPad } from 'react-countdown-now';
import "./TimeOut.scss";
 
const renderer = ({ minutes, seconds, completed }) => {
  return <div><span>{zeroPad(minutes, 2)}:{zeroPad(seconds, 2)}</span></div>;
};

class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timeout: props.timeout * 60 * 1000
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Countdown
        date={Date.now() + this.state.timeout}
        renderer={renderer}/>
    );
  }
}

export default Timer;
```

Comment: What do you want to test exactly?

Comment: Currently, there is a timer for 10 minutes and text you will be logged out due to inactivity. So I should test if it's working properly.

Comment: Ok, please include the test you have at the moment.

Comment: Is there any sense in that what I wrote?

Answer (score 1):

In my code, I have a function, WaitFor() that is supposed to pause the code and delay for a number of seconds.  For testing, I then do:

```
describe('WaitFor Testing', () => {
    it('should take at least 3 seconds to execute the test', () => {
        const Start:number = moment.now();
        WaitFor(3)
        const Duration = (moment.now() - Start);
        expect(Duration).toBeGreaterThan(2000);
        expect(Duration).toBeLessThan(10000);
    });
});
```

This causes the code to wait and see that the clock has at least waited for close to the three seconds.

For Jest, you can follow [Jest Timer Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks)

```
// __tests__/timerGame-test.js
'use strict';

jest.useFakeTimers();

test('waits 1 second before ending the game', () => {
    const timerGame = require('../timerGame');
    timerGame();

    expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(expect.any(Function), 1000);
});
```